# Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Readable' while using csvtojson

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am going to create method to read cvs files by url and using `csvtojson`
But when I used `request.get` I will get `Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Readable'`.
I create document but [Document](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csvtojson) but problem still existing here.
Onemore thing I could another npm to read files from url but I think, maybe those process exist in `csvtojson`. so I would use another npm to work with url data or how can i solve this problem

```
import { injectable } from "inversify";
import { BaseController } from "controllers/BaseController";
import * as csv from "csvtojson";
import {
    Path,
    POST,
    Description,
    CheckPermission,
    Tags,
    Authorization,
    Param,
    ContextRequest
} from "../../../lib/rest";
import { Action } from "../../../config/action-right";
import * as express from "express";

@injectable()
@Path("/api/import")
@Tags("Import")
export class ImportController implements BaseController {

    @Description("")
    @POST("/v1/import")
    @Authorization
    @CheckPermission(Action.Read)
    async import(
        @ContextRequest request: express.Request,
        @Param() filePath: string
    ): Promise<any> {
        csv()
            .fromStream(request.get("https://akhura.com/test.csv"))
            .on("csv", (csvRow) => {
                return csvRow;
            })
            .on("done", (error) => {
                return error;
            });
    }
}
```

### Error:

`[ts] Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Readable'.`

Comment: Did you solve this in the end? I tried to use `import * as request from "request";`

Answer (score 0):

The `request` object in your code snippet is `Express.Request` rather than node.js `request` module.

In Express, `Request.get` returns a value in string for specified key from request 
 header

Comment: "Uncaught Exception: path must be a string or Buffer

Comment: This maybe form data is invalid but I want to read from url not form data
`{
    "statusCode": 500,
    "error": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
    "message": "Uncaught Exception: path must be a string or Buffer"
}`